# is there any way to change the location of .SER files in CruiseControl

Tags: cruisecontrol

How can I change the path where .SER files are located, in CruiseControl. Now they are stored in CC home dir and there are too many of them (we have 28 projects). Please help

Comment: I guess You're talking about CruiseControl since I haven't found any .SER file on our CruiseControl**.NET** server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be currently supported. The `serializeProject` method in `Project` class doesn't seem to take that possibility into account:

```
public void serializeProject() {

    try {
        final ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name + ".ser"));
        try {
            s.writeObject(this);
            s.flush();
            debug("Serializing project to [" + name + ".ser]");
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.warn("Error serializing project to [" + name + ".ser]: "
                + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

where `name` is the name of the project.

Comment: I don't see any problem in filing such a request to CruiseControl team. Will you do that?